# Why escaped dot Regex in Java doesn't match a entry string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if a string matches a regex of a double type value in Java.

I want to understand why the following instruction prints "false".

```
System.out.println("1.".matches("1\\."));
```

And why this prints "false"

```
System.out.println("1.2".matches("[1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)?"));
```

And why this prints "true"

```
System.out.println("1.2a".matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"));
```

Comment: I get true for both.

Comment: you added double \ and now the question makes no sense

Comment: `System.out.println("1.".matches("1\\."));` returns `true`

Comment: Both your statement return true for me. https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineMixedHypothesis

Comment: I don't understand why I get false

Comment: Finally, I found the problem, It was caused by a process that is using another function returning boolean instead of the one posted above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double` `\` escapes a dot character for the `matches` method regex argument

```
System.out.println("1.".matches("1\\."));
```

Comment: Yes, I used double \ to escape the dot in order to match the word "1."
but it shows false
Thank you.

Comment: Finally, I found the problem, It was caused by a process that is using another function returning boolean instead of the one posted above.

Thank you!